# calculating this implicit function $\ln(x)(\log_{10}y)=1$

Tags: calculus

I'm working through this implicit function and would warmly appreciate your feedback.

$$\ln(x)(\log_{10}y)=1$$

my working out:

I take the derivative with respect to $x$ then $y$

$$\frac{1}{x}\log_{10}e\cdot\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Then calculate for $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ln(e^x)\cdot y = xy?$$

Comment: Why not simply solve for $y$ directly? In principle $\log_{10} y=whatever\implies y=10^{whatever}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the product rule.  For the sake of convenience, I will use $\ln$ to denote the natural logarithm, and $\log$ to denote the common logarithm.

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln x \log y] = \frac{d}{dx}[\ln x] \log y + (\ln x) \frac{d}{dx}[\log y] = \frac{1}{x} \log y + (\ln x)\frac{1}{y \ln 10} \frac{dy}{dx}.$$  Equating this to $0$ and solving for $dy/dx$ yields
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\log y}{x} \frac{y \ln 10}{\ln x} = - \frac{y \log y}{x \log x}. \tag{1}$$

You may also compute the explicit derivative: $1 = \ln x \log y$ implies $$y = 10^{1/\ln x} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln 10}{\ln x} \right),$$ hence $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\ln 10}{\ln x}\right] \exp \left(\frac{\ln 10}{\ln x}\right) = -\frac{\ln 10}{x (\ln x)^2} \exp\left(\frac{\ln 10}{\ln x}\right) = -\frac{10^{1/\ln x} \ln 10}{x (\ln x)^2}. \tag{2}$$  I leave it as an exercise to demonstrate that Equations $(1)$ an $(2)$ are equivalent.